# Using padding on new line and the padding cancel by himselfs

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to make space from the border by padding-left, though when I use `<br />` to wrap down the padding canceled on the new line that has been created.
Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block1">
<br />
<span class="text1">
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br /> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.block1{
    background: #e1d9d9;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 100px 70px 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #888888;
}
.text1{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/cy7x9j6g/3/embedded/result/

How can I fix the padding on new line issue?

Comment: Don't use break tags for spacing

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` to `.text1` - http://jsfiddle.net/nugc6a6x/

Comment: @Paulie_D So what should I use? if you watch carefully you will see that the automatic wraping is also causing this issue

Comment: <br /> is invlaid HTML.

Comment: You should use `margin-top` instead of `br` tag - http://jsfiddle.net/Lf0f1mj0/

Comment: Padding doesn't affect inline elements like spans as you might think. Use a paragraph or declare the span `inline-block`. a `p` tag would be optimal. - http://jsfiddle.net/cy7x9j6g/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use display:block/inline-block to use the pedding in it

```
.text1{display:block}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `span`s are `inline` elements and this is how they react to padding. To apply the padding in the way you expect either:

**Change the `span` to `display: inline-block;`:**

```css
.block1{
    background: #e1d9d9;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 100px 70px 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #888888;
}
.text1{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
        <br />
        <span class="text1">
            test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br /> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        </span>
        </div>
```

**Apply the padding to the parent instead:**

```css
.block1{
    background: #e1d9d9;
    width: 580px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 100px 70px 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #888888;
}
```

```html
        <div class="block1">
        <br />
        <span class="text1">
            test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br /> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        </span>
        </div>
```